# Uploading text file dictionary to python dictionary is not working

Tags: python, dictionary

I created a dictionary with data in this format in python. This is what my product.txt file contains

> {"6TII7N11RJ0J": {"productName": "Hisense 58" Class 4K UHD LED Roku Smart TV HDR 58R6E3", "productDescription": "58 Hisense 4k Roku Tv W/ Hdr", "productLocation_section": "N/A", "productLocation_zone": "N/A", "productLocation_aisle": "N/A", "productImg": "http://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/e00046a4-2eb3-48dc-b9ab-f0b750c384a7_1.fbb6003cb707252842bc913860c28568.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff", "productImg1": "/ip/Hisense-58-Class-4K-UHD-LED-Roku-Smart-TV-HDR-58R6E3/587182688", "productPrice": 278, "product_stock_status": "In Stock", "productBrand": "Hisense", "productRating": 4.5, "productDept": "Electronics", "store_available": "walmart", "_partitionKey": "store=name", "storeProductId": "6TII7N11RJ0J"}, "3MI7DUPI5M39": {"productName": "Hisense 40" Class FHD (1080P) Roku Smart LED TV (40H4030F1)", "productDescription": "Hisense 40" Class 1080P FHD LED Roku Smart TV 40H4030F1", "productLocation_section": 6, "productLocation_zone": "J", "productLocation_aisle": 23, "productImg": "http://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/104b5bcf-e7da-497b-87f6-0a5a56249d27_1.5c18e44aae7893f3044b2aeeed360603.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff", "productImg1": "/ip/Hisense-40-Class-FHD-1080P-Roku-Smart-LED-TV-40H4030F1/470905078", "productPrice": 178, "product_stock_status": "Out of Stock", "productBrand": "Hisense", "productRating": 4.5, "productDept": "Electronics", "store_available": "walmart", "_partitionKey": "store=walmart", "storeProductId": "3MI7DUPI5M39"}

product.txt file's content were created through this code

```
  try:
        # WRITE THE PRODUCT TO FILE
        productFile = "storeData/store/productDir.txt"
        with open(productFile, "w") as pfile:
            pfile.write(json.dumps(NewProductDict))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

now I need to open product.txt file and read the content back into a dictionary in python. This is one of many codes i tried.

```
def uploadProductDir():
    productFile1 = "storeData/store/productDir.txt"
    with open(productFile1, "r") as pfile:
          developer = json.load(pfile)
    for key, value in developer.items():
        print(key, ":", value, "\n")
```

but i am getting this error

> Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

how could I upload a text file containing dictionary data format above in python so that i can iterate through the dictionary. This was a python json dictionary that i mistakenly saved to a .txt instead of .json file. Now I want to import from the .txt file back in python so that i can work with the data.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to convert to what? Is it python dictionary to .json and then back to python dictionary?

Comment: yes it was python json dictionary saved to a text file that needs to be converted back to python json

Comment: Can you provide an example which includes the data before it is converted to JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I resaved the .txt as .json file and the code

```
def uploadProductDir():
    productFile1 = "storeData/store/productDir.json"
    with open(productFile1, "r") as pfile:
         developer = json.load(pfile)
    for key, value in developer.items():
        print(key, ":", value, "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without seeing the whole file, but it seems like your file doesn't start with { and end with } (if your whole json file is supposed to be a dictionary)

Answer (score -1):

You're json is invalid. As mentioned by @Grinjero, it needs the starting `{`. It also has a extra double quote in the product name value.

You can use `eval` to convert the json to a dictionary.

This code worked for me:

```
import json

NewProductDict = '''
{
    "6TII7N11RJ0J": {
        "productName": "Hisense 58\' Class 4K UHD LED Roku Smart TV HDR 58R6E3",
        "productDescription": "58 Hisense 4k Roku Tv W/ Hdr",
        "productLocation_section": "N/A",
        "productLocation_zone": "N/A",
        "productLocation_aisle": "N/A",
        "productImg": "http: //i5.walmartimages.com/asr/e00046a4-2eb3-48dc-b9ab-f0b750c384a7_1.fbb6003cb707252842bc913860c28568.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff",
        "productImg1": "/ip/Hisense-58-Class-4K-UHD-LED-Roku-Smart-TV-HDR-58R6E3/587182688",
        "productPrice": 278,
        "product_stock_status": "In Stock",
        "productBrand": "Hisense",
        "productRating": 4.5,
        "productDept": "Electronics",
        "store_available": "walmart",
        "_partitionKey": "store=name",
        "storeProductId": "6TII7N11RJ0J"
    }
}
'''.strip()
   
def saveFile():
    try:
        # WRITE THE PRODUCT TO FILE
        productFile = "tmpjson.txt"
        with open(productFile, "w") as pfile:
            pfile.write(json.dumps(NewProductDict))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)  

def uploadProductDir():
    productFile1 = "tmpjson.txt"
    with open(productFile1, "r") as pfile:
          developer = eval(json.load(pfile))  # convert json to dictionary
    for key, value in developer.items():
        print(key, ":", value, "\n")

    print(developer['6TII7N11RJ0J']['productName']) # confirm structure
        
saveFile()
uploadProductDir()
```

Output

```
6TII7N11RJ0J : {'productName': "Hisense 58' Class 4K UHD LED Roku Smart TV HDR 58R6E3", 'productDescription': '58 Hisense 4k Roku Tv W/ Hdr', 'productLocation_section': 'N/A', 'productLocation_zone': 'N/A', 'productLocation_aisle': 'N/A', 'productImg': 'http: //i5.walmartimages.com/asr/e00046a4-2eb3-48dc-b9ab-f0b750c384a7_1.fbb6003cb707252842bc913860c28568.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff', 'productImg1': '/ip/Hisense-58-Class-4K-UHD-LED-Roku-Smart-TV-HDR-58R6E3/587182688', 'productPrice': 278, 'product_stock_status': 'In Stock', 'productBrand': 'Hisense', 'productRating': 4.5, 'productDept': 'Electronics', 'store_available': 'walmart', '_partitionKey': 'store=name', 'storeProductId': '6TII7N11RJ0J'}

Hisense 58' Class 4K UHD LED Roku Smart TV HDR 58R6E3
```

Comment: Yes it does start and end with braces. I forgot to add it to the question

Comment: Alternatively, escape the double quote in the string with `\\` like so: "Hisense 58\" Class 4K UHD LED Roku Smart TV HDR 58R6E3".

Comment: Why use `eval()`, when `json.load` returns a dictionary?